# AngularJs 1.6 Component BIndings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

routing an angularjs component with camelcase binding doesn't work for me, I don't know why.

Here's the example

Component

```
angular.
  module('pdaFile').
  component('pdaFile', {
    templateUrl: 'app/myComponent/myComponent.html',
    bindings:{
        data:"<",
        dataFileId:"@",
        datafileid:"@",
        id:"@"
    },
    controller: ['NgTableParams','UserAuthService',
      function pdaFileController(NgTableParams,UserAuthService) {
        var self=this;

...

self.$onInit = function () {
            console.log(self.dataFileId); // undefined
            console.log(self.id); // OK
            console.log(self.datafileid); //OK

        };


appConfig.js

..
```

// Router

```
angular.
  module('app')
      .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
         function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
     $routeProvider.
when('/pda', {
           template: '<pda-file id="pippo" datafileid="current" data-file-id="current"></pda-file>'})
     .
```

..

I'm not able to fill the binding param dataFileId in any way. It's always undefined.
I tried with

```
<pda-file data-file-id="current"></pda-file>'

<pda-file dataFileId="current"></pda-file>'
```

and other ways. Instead the non camelcase param datafileid and id work perfectly.

Someone can tell me why ?

Comment: I would suggest not to use words like `data-` or `data` as attributes names prefixes

Comment: You're right. Changing from dataFileId to dtFileId works perfectly, using dt-file-id as attribute

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
data-file-id="current"
```

Or

```
file-id="current"
```

Then

```
bindings:{
    fileId:"@",
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried. It works with fileId. The problem is in the use of "data" as prefix, which leads to not good behavior, as Ferie suggestion. Using dtFileId also works, and dt-file-id as tag attribute

Comment: So that fixes your issue?